# Why baseclass calls method of subclass?

Tags: java, subclass, base-class

I encounter some code like the following:
BaseClass:

```
public class BaseClass {
    String name = "Base";

    public BaseClass() {
        printName();
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(name + "——Base");
    }
}
```

DrivedClass:

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    String name = "Sub";

    public SubClass() {
        printName();
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(name + "——Sub");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass();
    }
}
```

When run the code, the output is:

**null——Sub

Sub——Sub**

while it should be:

**Base——Base

Sub——Sub**

I wonder why the BaseClass constructor calls the SubClass method, can anybody explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why downvoted? I think this is an interesting question about constructors and overriding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line(**"null——Sub"**) is printed as a result of `printName()` of `SubClass` being called from the `BaseClass` constructor. When `printName()` is called from `BaseClass` constructor, since there is an overridden method available in the `SubClass`, that `printName()` is called.

At this point of time, since the `SubClass` constructor is not yet called, the `name` field of `SubClass` is undefined and thus prints `null`.

The second line(**"Sub——Sub"**) is printed as a result of `printName()` of `SubClass` being called from the `SubClass` constructor. This time around, the instance fields are loaded and thus, the `name` prints the proper value (i.e) "Sub".

The thing to note here is that, both the times, the `printName()` method of `SubClass` is only called. Just that the first time around(because it's called from the `super` class constructor), its instance fields are not defined and the second time around, they are.

Comment: Many tools will warn about calling non final methods from constructors

Comment: @MattCoubrough - Am not very sure how many common IDEs support this though.

Comment: Netbeans will, can't remember for Eclipse, but noobs can get burned by this unintuitive gotcha, so a warning is a Good thing!

Comment: @MattCoubrough - unfortunately/fortunately, I've used only eclipse and it never gave out such interesting warnings :)

Comment: @R.J Is this something like method shadowing compared to variable shadowing?